# How to fetch first 4 rows for each column value in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I am running the following query:

```
select item, product, design, price 
from product 
fetch first 4 rows only
```

It is fetching all first 4 rows from the complete database, but suppose I have 10 items and every item has 10 products and I want to fetch any 4 products from each item. How do I do that?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question. Basically you have to give a number to each product according to a defined order and take only those between 1 and 4. This can be done with [`ROWNUMBER() OVER(...)`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-olap-specification#sdx-synid_frag-numbering-specification)

Comment: On a side note: Your query selects the "first" rows only in the sense that these are the first rows it happens to see when you run it. These can even be different rows when you run the query again. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, `FETCH FIRST ROWS` is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is absolutely very logical and I don't know how you received 2 negative votes but I appreciate you for asking this logical question.

I understood your question very well and the attached below script will provide you with the expected result: (will provide you the 4 products from each item)

```
select test.item, test.product, test.design, test.price from(
select item, product, design, price, row_number() over(partition by item order by product asc) as rn
from product) as test
where test.rn<=4;
```

please use this script to get the expected result and let me know for any additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot .. You just solved my big issue